# Why doesn't using LET as an optional throw an error, as it is an implicit comparison to zero - inconsistency in Swift Intro book?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, xcode6, option-type, let

I'm reading through the Swift documentation, and hung up on a what I see as an inconsistency in the docs.

#### Quote 1 - Control Flow Section

> In an **if** statement, the conditional must be a Boolean expression--this means that code such as **if score { ... }** is an error, not an implicit comparison to zero.

So a strict "Boolean," would be either TRUE or FALSE.

#### Quote 2 - Control Flow Section

> You can use **if** and **let** together to work with values that might be missing. These values are represented as optionals. An optional value either contains a value or contains **nil** to indicate that the value is missing. Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value to mark the value as optional

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

> if the optional value is **nil**, the conditional is **false**

So by "Boolean" they seem to mean "truthy/falsy," as **nil** implicitly means **false**

> and the code in braces is skipped. Otherwise, the optional value is unwrapped and assigned to the constant after **let**, which makes the unwrapped value available inside the block of code.

So here is where I see an inconsistency. In the code sample above, since optionalName has a value, the `name` variable is assigned "John Appleseed."

So in the comparison, we end up with a **NON-BOOLEAN EXPRESSION**; specifically, "John Appleseed." This is "truthy," but NOT boolean, which contradicts point 1!

In other words--in code--after the value is assigned in the let, we have:

```
if "John Appleseed" {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Based on **Quote 1**, this should throw an error, because it is not a Boolean expression.

Comment: "If" by itself is a boolean expression. "If let" together is not, and it doesn't say it is. Yo're comparing 2 different things just because they both use the same keyword that do different things in 2 different cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are kind of right, it is not consistent, it should not mention *Boolean Expression* but rather a *Logic Value*. Here is what the [Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-XID_949) says about `if`:

> The value of any condition in an if statement must have a type that conforms to the LogicValue protocol. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding.

Please note that optional binding here is **not** treated as an expression. It is **not** an assignment in if like in C. It is just a *special case* of an `if` statement that succeeds when the bound value is not nil.

None of this is valid in Swift:

```
x = y = 10 // () is not convertible to Int
if z = optional { } // type () does not conform to LogicValue
if let z = optional && z > 5 { } // bound value must be of Optional type
if (let z = optional) && z > 5 { } // pattern variable binding cannot appear in expression
```

**Edit:**
At first my answer stated that "assignment is not an expression in Swift", but technically that is incorrect. Assignment is an expression, but of type `()` a.k.a. `Void`. This is valid Swift:

```
var v = ()
var x = 0

v = x = 10 // x = 10; v = ()
```

**Edit2:**
Just to make this perfectly clear, when you use `if let` or `if var` it is not an *assignment* to an existing variable, a new variable/constant is introduced that is scoped to the inside of the `if` block:

```
var x = 0
var y : Int? = 10
if var x = y { // new variable x is introduced
    println(x) // prints 10
    x = 20     // neither affects y nor 'outer' x
}
if let x = y { // new constant x is introduced
    println(x) // prints 10
}
if let y = y { // introduce new y shadowing the original
    println(y) // prints 10
}
println(x)     // prints 0

//if x = y { } // does not compile
```

Comment: It is valid to say `if let z = optional, z > 5 { }`, though (SE-0099).

Answer (score 2):

Optional binding is a language construct in Swift. It is shorthand for this:

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if optionalName {
    let name = optionalName!
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Optionals are actually defined as a generic `enum` type in Swift, and they implement the `LogicValue` protocol, which is what's required for use in a control structure like `if` or `while`. Here's the relevant parts of the `Optional` definition:

```
enum Optional<T> : LogicValue, Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    ...
    /// Allow use in a Boolean context.
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool
    ...
}
```

Comment: But that's exactly my point! Based on QUOTE 1 in my OP, this should throw an error.

Comment: It doesn't, since optionals conform to `LogicValue`, which is what if statements look for. It's different than `if 5 {`. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to assignment and evaluation of conditional expression in C:

```
if (c = 1) {
}
```

1 is assigned to c, then c is evaluated - it is not 0, so that evaluates to true, and the if branch is executed.

Something similar happens in swift (when using `if` and `let` together on an optional) :

```
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

if `optionalName` is nil, the `let name = optionalName` evaluates to `false`, and the if branch is skipped. If `optionalName` is not nil, the assignment is performed, and the `let name = optionalName` evaluates to `true`, so the if branch is executed.

**Addendum** It is probably not clear, but **if `optionalName` is nil, no assignment takes place**. The expression evaluates to false and the if branch is skipped.

Comment: Ah, so there are two values at work here. The first is the boolean value to which the expression evaluates; in this case, `true`. The second is the value that is assigned to the variable; in this case, `John Appleseed`

Comment: The one who **downvoted** is invited to explain the reason for that. If there's a mistake in my answer, then I think it's better to let everybody know. The downvote affects me only, but everybody can read the answer and the comments. I'm not against downvotes, but they should be followed by a proper explanation

Comment: Fully agree on downvote comments. IMO they should be required. Should i mark `slazyk`'s answer as accepted?

Comment: This isn't accurate -- `let name = optionalName` doesn't evaluate to false, the status of the optional is examined first.

Comment: While your answer more or less explains what happens, analogy to C is misleading/incorrect. Especially since you mention that '*The same* happens in swift' and then you say that the order of assignment and evaluation is different from C. Not to mention that you cannot use assignments like this, only binding declarations.

Comment: Well, I think it's clear that they are not the same thing, but their result is the same. I mentioned C to make a comparison, not to say that C and swift are the same, nor to say that it's possible to make assignments like in C. The question is about using `if` and `let` together, so my answer is in that context. By the way, I accept the downvotes and won't complain about them, now that I have an explanation.

Comment: The reason it matters that they're different is that the assignment doesn't happen if `optionalName` is `nil`.

Comment: That's what I wrote (but in the opposite way): If optionalName is not nil, the assignment is performed. Just made that explicit with a note in the answer

Comment: That is not the point. It is not an assignment to an existing variable, it is a declaration of a new variable/constant, so it does not really matter whether assigning happens or not. Even if it did, you would not know because of the limited scope of the binding.

Comment: There is no mention in my answer about creation of new or usage of existing. I just made a **comparison pertinent to the question**, and of course I couldn't describe all differences between the 2 languages, pretty much as I couldn't explain what is the difference between a horse and a car if I am comparing one to the other to explain the concept of moving goods from A to B. I am sure the comparison I made explains the "why". But I respect opinions, either positive or negative.

Comment: Yes, I know that you don't mention new or existing variables. But your answer still mentions assignment happening or not. My previous comment was actually in reply to @NateCook who said that it matters because no assignment happens if `optionalName` is `nil`. Rather than that, the difference is that there is no assignment to existing variables at all.